# When using an iframe how do I include javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, timer

I am relatively new to front-end development with HTML5/JavaScript.

I guess I should've researched this before.  I needed to create an iframe that will include a javascript countdown timer and a javascript text effect.

The iframe renders OK but it doesn't the timer isn't showing countdown in real-time and the text effect is not rendering as well.

I wanted this to be embeddable similar to the way you embed a flash video or something...

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have an iFrame like:

```
<iframe src="someSource" id="frameID"></iframe>
```

And your script is in an external *myScripts.js* file you may want to append a new script to the  of the iFrame... something like:

```
$("#frameID").contents().find("head").append("<script type='text/javascript' src='resources/script/script.js'>");
```

Edit:
If you have a function *functionToCall()* you want to call inside the iframe (as opposed to embedding an external file), you can do something like this:

```
  document.getElementById('frameID').contentWindow.functionToCall();
```

Comment: Thanks @alemangui.  I am too new to know what that means... I am sorry but can you please clarify.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok sure, Are you using jQuery? Also, do your Javascript files reside in external .js files?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping.  I am using a mix of inline and external files.

Comment: I'll add an edit regarding calling functions as opposed to including javascript files...

Comment: Thanks for the update.  So i guess I add this part"$("#frameID").contents().find("head").append("myScripts.js");" to the external js script?

Comment: Well, you can wherever as long as the document is loaded and the iFrame exists

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19846/discussion-between-kpo-and-alemangui)

Comment: @alemangui Hey I noticed you accepted my edit. I've a current issue that is kinda the same as OP but not quite. Maybe you know the answer. I'd appreciate if you could take a look as you might know the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530638/how-to-include-css-and-javascript-in-iframe