# how to include css and javascript in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

My css and javascript aren't taken into consideration in iframes.
For example I've this iframe :

```
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField"/>
```

Where I inject a .css file after page load:

```
$(document).ready(iFrameOn);

function iFrameOn() {
    richTextField.document.designMode = "On";
    richTextField.document.head.innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iframe.css">';
}
```

In chrome the head of my iframe will contain my stylesheet but it won't have any effect, in ie it's not even included.

Anyway I noticed that alert doesn't work for me on jsfiddle while it works for other users. [Take this code for instance](http://jsfiddle.net/Yazpj/2628/). No alert dialog appears for me on chrome. I think this might be linked. Any idea why this would happen ?

Comment: What is the `src` url of the iframe? You may need to load the CSS file with ajax and insert the code directly into the iframe into a `<style>` element.  You are using a relative URL, but it doesn't know what it's relevant to.

Comment: If the domain name of the iframe source is not the same as the domain name of the page you're loading your iframe on, then you can't inject your css to it. Here is a wiki link on that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @AndrewLyndem there is no domain name or src. I create an iframe as text editor then build the content of the doc myself. That's the point.

Comment: @PitaJ there is no r src. I create an iframe as text editor then build the content of the doc myself. That's the point.